Spring boot - Hibernate - Many to many - Saving/Updating Entity

package com.dharma.associations.manyToMany.entities;


import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "programmer")
public class Programmer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(name = "programmers_projects",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "programmer_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public Set<Project> getProjects() {
        return projects;
    }

    public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects) {
        this.projects = projects;
    }

    public void addProject(Project project){
        if(project == null)
            return;
        this.projects.add(project);
        project.getProgrammers().add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Programmer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", salary=" + salary +
                '}';
    }
}

package com.dharma.associations.manyToMany.entities;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "projects")
    private Set<Programmer> programmers = new HashSet<>();

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Set<Programmer> getProgrammers() {
        return programmers;
    }

    public void setProgrammers(Set<Programmer> programmers) {
        this.programmers = programmers;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Project{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    public void addProgrammer(Programmer programmer) {
        if(programmer == null)
            return;
        this.programmers.add(programmer);
        programmer.getProjects().add(this);
    }
}

These are entities, Project and programmer they both have a many to many relationship and obv the db has three tables for this relationship.
@Test
@Transactional
public void textCreateNewProg(){


    Programmer programmer = programmerRepository.findById(30).get();

    Project e = new Project();
    e.setName("jjjk");
    Project f = new Project();
    f.setName("JJJJk");

    programmer.addProject(e);
    programmer.addProject(f);

    programmerRepository.save(programmer);

    entityManager.clear();entityManager.flush();
    Programmer programmer2 = programmerRepository.findById(30).get();
    System.out.println(programmer2.getId() + " " + programmer2.getProjects());


}

When i ran this test, the test is passing however the db is not updating (none of the tables are updating) but i could see that the auto increment value is increasing.
The log is :
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.name,
        p1_0.salary 
    from
        programmer p1_0 
    where
        p1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.programmer_id,
        p1_1.id,
        p1_1.name 
    from
        programmers_projects p1_0 
    join
        project p1_1 
            on p1_1.id=p1_0.project_id 
    where
        p1_0.programmer_id=?

Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.project_id,
        p1_1.id,
        p1_1.name,
        p1_1.salary 
    from
        programmers_projects p1_0 
    join
        programmer p1_1 
            on p1_1.id=p1_0.programmer_id 
    where
        p1_0.project_id=?

Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        project
        (name) 
    values
        (?)
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        project
        (name) 
    values
        (?)
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.id,
        p1_0.name,
        p1_0.salary 
    from
        programmer p1_0 
    where
        p1_0.id=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        p1_0.programmer_id,
        p1_1.id,
        p1_1.name 
    from
        programmers_projects p1_0 
    join
        project p1_1 
            on p1_1.id=p1_0.project_id 
    where
        p1_0.programmer_id=?

30 [Project{id=25, name='ABC Bank'}]

Please help
Tried saving new programmer with new projects, resulting in new rows in tables, but this updation seems to be still not working.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.
